# Vector, ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class numeric

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I'm trying to make a simple boxplot with ggplot2. I've got a vector with numbers but when I type in the code an this error message appears:

> Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class numeric.

What does that mean?

Code:

```
vector1 <- c(x1, x2, x3, ...)
library(ggplot2) 
ggplot(vector1, aes(x=x, y=value)) + boxplot()
```

Comment: it means ggplot only works with data.frames.

Comment: try : `v <- data.frame(vec=vector1) ; ggplot(v,aes(x=1,y=vec)) + geom_boxplot()`

Comment: Related thread with datasets here https://stackoverflow.com/q/38277826/54964

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `qplot` as follows:

```
qplot(1,vector1, geom="boxplot")
```

Or (as @scoa pointed out) concert vector1 to a `data.frame` as `ggplot` operates only on `data.frame`s and not on vectors. `qplot` is a convenience wrapper for very simple plots.