# mtcars ggplot doesn't know how to deal with class numeric

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am just trying to make a simple plot using mtcars and ggplot:

```
ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=mpg,y=hp))+geom_line(mpg,hp,col=cyl)
```

but I get the error:

> ggplot doesnt know how to deal with class numeric

What is going on?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Why are you passing `mpg` and `hp` twice and why aren't they mapped in `aes()` in geom_line?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In R, dealing with Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class numeric](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29953011/in-r-dealing-with-error-ggplot2-doesnt-know-how-to-deal-with-data-of-class-nu)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You may want to check out the following links: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
  and [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You should read some ggplot basics. What you need is just `ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=mpg,y=hp))+geom_line(aes(col=cyl))`.

Comment: When I paste the code snippet to `R` I do get a different error message `Error in layer(data = data, mapping = mapping, stat = stat, geom = GeomLine,  : 
  object 'cyl' not found` with R version 3.3.0 and ggplot2 2.1.0

Comment: @steveb This is a working MCV example and a clear question (although a typical beginners Q). I see no reason for downvoting.

Comment: @UweBlock: That's exactly the same error message I got with the questioners code. R 3.3.1, ggplot2 2.1.0

Comment: @Evan Which version of `R` and `ggplot2` are you using?

Comment: @Hack-R Except for the same error message, the possible duplicate question contains a bunch of superfluous code. I can't see what the questioner could have learned from this for the actual question.

Comment: @UweBlock FWIW, I didn't down vote.  I always comment instead of down vote.  I mainly wanted to see a better idea of what OP was looking for as this is something that is in the documentation for `ggplot2::geom_line`.  The usage for `ggplot2::geom_line` is `geom_line(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, stat = "identity", position = "identity", 
  ...)` where the `mapping` is the first argument.  I will remove my comments  if I am missing something.

Comment: @steveb Thanks for the explaining your motivation. I noted that the question was downvoted several times and I was puzzled why. The question seems to be a typical `ggplot` beginners questions. It reminds of the many tar pits I used to trap in when moving from `lattice` graphics to `ggplot`.

Comment: @UweBlock No worries. I am just attempting to keep SO addressing things not already in SO or in the documentation (assuming clearly stated in the documentation, which is not always the case) and hope others will point out if I stray :-)  In short, if a question has been answered in the documentation (but not necessarily in S0) it likely should likely not be on SO.  I am often puzzled at down votes w/o explanation (comments).

Comment: Related thread with vector here https://stackoverflow.com/q/35525240/54964

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to specify all aesthetics in one place and to coerce `cyl` to `factor` for colour coding as categorial variable.

```
ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=hp, colour=factor(cyl))) + geom_line()
```

will create
[image]

Comment: That works very well. Could you explain to me why what I had doesnt work? I made the code following this document: https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwib7vGlwOfNAhVE6iYKHY7zBskQjRwIBw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fblog.rstudio.org%2F2015%2F03%2F30%2Fdata-visualization-cheatsheet-plus-spanish-translations%2F&bvm=bv.126130881,d.eWE&psig=AFQjCNFOvZK4EPjQIJzk2qu0rk0-TND-OQ&ust=1468192196930217  I rely on this for a lot of my graphs in ggplot, so if there is something wrong with it I would love to know.

Comment: @Evan I carefully read the _Data Visualization with ggplot2 Cheat Sheet_  you are referring to. There is an example `ggplot(mpg, aes(hwy, cty)) + geom_point(aes(color = cyl))` which looks similar to your Q at first sight but note the call to  `aes` in `geom_point`. Another example uses `qplot` which has a simplified syntax but is less flexible. Calls to `qplot` and `ggplot` must not be mixed (well, I never tried to...). Please, google for `Hadley Wickam ggplot2 book`. The book helped me a lot in creating complex graphs.

Answer (score 0):

See if you get better results passing hte argument to `aes` inside `geom_line`:

```
ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=mpg,y=hp))+geom_line(aes(x=mpg,y=hp,colour=cyl) )
```

I think the results are a bit clearer if you add a grouping parameter to the basic `aes` spec:

```
ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=mpg,y=hp, group=cyl)) + 
        geom_line(aes(x=mpg,y=hp,colour=cyl) )
```

And even better legend anotation with a factor() on cyl:

```
ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=mpg,y=hp, group=cyl))+ 
       geom_line(aes(x=mpg,y=hp,col=factor(cyl)) )
```